# Applying a Discount Code to a Completed Order in Expresso Store?

Tags: expresso-store

Just curious whether there’s any way to apply a discount to an order that has been completed using Expresso Store. Applying this discount would change the balance due (to an amount owing back to the customer), then a partial refund could be issued via our payment gateway.

The only way I can see doing this payment gateway is to edit the price of one of the items currently associated with the order.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something built into Store currently you would need to write an extension using one of the hooks to apply the discount code then send refund amount to your payment gateway.

I believe that only the order status hooks would be called from the CP when changing orders.

All extension hooks can be seen [here](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html)